# Install & configure mod_ssl on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, https, mod-ssl, configuration

I am trying to support HTTPS traffic with the mod_ssl module on my website. I am running an Amazon EC2 instance for my server. I have installed and configured the basic LAMP packages. However, when I go to put in SSL-specific commands in my apache config files (ie. `SSLEngine`, `SSLCertificateFile`, etc) it spits out an error and says that I have a syntax error or the module is not loaded.

My next step was to try `$ sudo yum install mod_ssl`. However, yum comes back and says, "Processing Conflict...Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools". So, I figured that mod_ssl is included in the httpd-tools package. I then ran `$ sudo yum install httpd24-tools` but it comes back and tells me I already have that package installed.

Now how come I have the httpd-tools package installed, and mod_ssl is not loaded in my system? Isn't mod_ssl included in the httpd-tools package? I created a test php file `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` just to make sure. My suspicions were confirmed—no *'mod_ssl'* is listed under the apache2handler loaded modules table in phpinfo.

So, I'm not exactly sure how to load in/install/configure mod_ssl with the Amazon Linux AMI's. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my current specs:

- Amazon Linux AMI 2012.09
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 5.4

Ran this command to setup server:

```
$ sudo yum install httpd24 php54 php54-devel php54-mysql php54-common php54-gd php54-xml php54-mbstring php54-mcrypt php54-pecl-apc mysql-server mod_ssl openssl httpd54-devel mysql libjpeg libpng phpmyadmin
```

Comment: What Apache config did you use? I'd guess syntax error over module not loaded, as it should be standard in most distributions at this point.

Comment: Came across an answer while scouring forums. _"All Apache modules built for httpd-2.4 have been renamed mod24\_<name>. So for the SSL Apache module the package is called mod24\_ssl."_

Solution: `$ sudo yum install mod24_ssl`. This installed the package successfully, but now when I try and restart my Apache server, it fails to start httpd. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: :) Sometimes it's the easy things. ;) All I had to do was tweak a few settings in my _/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf_ file. Good to go! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please add your answer on the answers section and mark it as answered. I had the same problem and did come across this answer but i didn't read the comments until days later when i realized it actually had the answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try to run `yum install mod24_ssl` instead, which I think you've already done. Any packages that have additional versions usually require the version to be specified for any dependencies. So everything for `php54` would be prefixed with `php54-`.

If you're ever unsure, you can always do a `yum search` with some keywords. For example: `yum search mod ssl` lists the available packages.

Comment: No problems, glad you got it to work! :)

Comment: OMG, Works perfectly!

Comment: No problems, glad it was some help over a year later :)

Comment: Works like a charm